# Infinite loop hangs in run() -method (Android emulator)

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

we're trying to build an application that records the decibel level every seconds or so. The problem is that we need to have an infinite loop in the run() method that polls the decibel level, but when we add the infinite loop, it hangs. Could anyone point us to the right direction? Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
package tpsip.tpsip;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class tpsip extends Activity implements Runnable{

private TextView decibelMeter;
private TextView timeRemaining;
private Button button;
private int safetyTime;


ExposureCalculator calculator = new ExposureCalculator();
Handler handler = new Handler();
Thread thread = new Thread();
LogicLayer logicLayer = new LogicLayer();


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.safetyTime = 28800; //8 hours of safe time when the decibel level is between 90-92, levels below this are not considered dangerous to hearing

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.decibelMeter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    this.decibelMeter.setText("0 dB");

    this.timeRemaining = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    this.timeRemaining.setText("Safety time remaining " + safetyTime + " seconds");

    this.button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    button.setText("Ear protection not needed");

    handler.post(thread);

    this.run();

}

@Override
public void run() {
        int a = 10;
    while(true) {
        this.decibelMeter.setText("0safsafsafa dB");
        if (a == Math.random() * 100) break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: See [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29). The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the opertaion on a different thread and change the UI when needed from there using handler or `runOnUIThread()`. currently the method is being called as a regullar method and runs in infinite loop which doesn't let your UI be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the infinite loop in the UI thread? This is something you must never do. The application will become nonresponsive and "hang", because it cannot get messages from the operating system any more. Use another thread to run the loop.

The easiest way to do this would be to add a class that extends `Thread` and put your "run" method there. However, remember that you cannot access the UI from another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Like what others have said, you must not run long running operations on the Main/UI thread. Your app locked up because onCreate() can never return and update the UI.

Use AsyncTask instead: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html